# Using ref in vue to modify the style of an element sends an error in the toggle routing

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I use Vue to bind an img tag through ref in a route and have it rotate periodically. But it show `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. I know it's because `this.$refs.image` becomes undefined after switching the routing, but I don't know how to solve this problem so that it doesn't give an error. Can you help me?

```
<img :src="this.picUrl" ref="image">

rotateMusicLogo() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.deg += 0.15;
        if(this.deg >= 360)  this.deg = 0;
        this.$refs.image.style.transform = `rotate(${this.deg}deg)`;
    }, 10)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should destroy your timer on the `beforeDestroy` hook:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                timer: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            rotateMusicLogo () {
                this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                    this.deg += 0.15;
                    if(this.deg >= 360)  this.deg = 0;
                    this.$refs.image.style.transform = `rotate(${this.deg}deg)`;
                }, 10)
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.rotateMusicLogo()
        },
        beforeDestroy () {
            clearInterval(this.timer)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just clear the interval you created when the route change. So, in the component;

```
watch:{
    $route (to, from){
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
}
```